# Does Okhttp GET request uses gzip as default?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I need to know whether the response of the GET request is compressed/decompressed using gzip or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OkHttp will do transparent gzip on response bodies unless you disable the feature with this **Header**:

```
Accept-Encoding: identity
```